# Add to my executable the Java Cryptography Extension Unlimited Strength or autoinstall it

Tags: java, cryptography

My program is a simetric crypter that uses a key lenght of 256. When I use it on a computer that didn't have the JCE installed (for no key lenght), it crashes with the following error:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

So it is because the computer didn't have the extension that allows to use this keysize.

Is there any way to put the java unlimited strength extension with my program for use it without install? Or can I open a dialog for install it automatically?

In other hand, there are a better solution for do an AES encryption with a 256 key? Maybe another API allows me to do it without adding any extension? (like bouncy castle).

Answer (score 1):

JCE Unlimited Strength can be downloaded from the Oracle website.  (Or at least, I can download it in Australia.)

However, you first need to agree to the Oracle [Binary Code Licende for Java](http://javascript:showAgreement('jce-7-oth-JPR');), and clause 7 says this:

> *"7. EXPORT REGULATIONS. You agree that U.S. export control laws and other applicable export and import laws govern your use of the Software, including technical data; additional information can be found on Oracle's Global Trade Compliance web site (http://www.oracle.com/us/products/export). You agree that neither the Software nor any direct product thereof will be exported, directly, or indirectly, in violation of these laws, or will be used for any purpose prohibited by these laws including, without limitation, nuclear, chemical, or biological weapons proliferation."*

---

So to answer your questions about JCE

> Is there any way to put the java unlimited strength extension with my program for use it without install?

I'm not a lawyer, but I think that the Oracle license says that you can only use the JCE code (and that includes distributing it in your product) if your usage conforms to US export law.  Be aware that crypto software is specifically restricted.

> Or can I open a dialog for install it automatically?

That is unclear, both legally, and technically.

---

> Maybe another API allows me to do it without adding any extension? (like bouncy castle).

Bouncy Castle is also covered by US export laws.  Furthermore, in the [Bouncy Castle FAQs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions), FAQ #1 says that key lengths in Bouncy Castle's Java SE compatible crypto provides are governed by the same mechanism (and policy files) that JCE uses.  However FAQ #10 says:

> *"At the time of writing (16 May 2007) Bouncy Castle is approved classified under ECCN code 5D002 and approved for export under License Exception TSU."*

---

I also looked up "License Exception TSU" and I found that it is defined in the [Exceptions to the Export  Administration  Regulations (EAR)](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/forms-documents/doc_view/986-740)  as:

> *"§ 740.13 TECHNOLOGY AND SOFTWARE UNRESTRICTED (TSU)*
>
> *This  license  exception  authorizes exports  and 
>   reexports  of operation technology and  software; 
>   sales technology and software; software updates 
>   (bug fixes); “mass market” software subject to 
>   the   General   Software   Note;   and   encryption 
>   source code (and corresponding object code) **that 
>   would  be  considered  publicly  available**  under 
>   §734.3(b)(3) of the  EAR."*

And so on.

It looks promising, especially for an open source product, but I would still advise getting advise to a **real** expert; i.e. a professional with appropriate legal training.

Comment: Bouncycastle provides two APIs. The first API is available through the standard JCE, for which Bouncycastle supplies the crypto provider "under the hood". That API is governed by the same keysize restrictions as the standard Oracle providers. The second API is what Bouncycastle calls the "lightweight API". This is distinct from the provider and has no keysize restrictions. You can use AES-256 from this second API without having the Unlimited Crypto policy files.

Comment: So, with the Bouncycastle lightweight API, I could develop a software that crypts (without any extension) with a 256 key? I have the TrueCrypt (or others crypters) examples, that they can crypt with this key lenght but it doesn't needed to install anything more in addition.

Comment: @selan - I am not a lawyer.  Talk to a professional.

Comment: @GregS said that: [The second API is what Bouncycastle calls the "lightweight API". This is distinct from the provider and has no keysize restrictions]. And my program is not for comercial use, only for educational, so I only want to find a form for use an AES-256 key without install any unlimited crypto policy files....

Comment: @selan - I don't think that GregS is qualified to give advice on legal matters, and this is definitely a legal matter.

Comment: @StephenC: The library can do that, it isn't a legal question. The legal question involves the export control laws and their applicability, something that a lawyer can advise on, not me.

Comment: @GregS - It is definitely a legal question as to what the OP is permitted to do with regard to the US export laws.  Neither you or I are qualified to answer that.

Comment: That's not his question.

Comment: By implication, it is.  He asked "can I do it", and there are two aspects to that - can I do it from a technical perspective, and can I do it from a legal perspective.  Now my opinion *as a non-lawyer* is that what he is probably going to do is allowed because of the "Licensing Exception TSU".   But that is just my unqualified opinion.

Comment: Ok, my question was "if I can crypt with 256 key without adding any cryptographic extension". The fact is, for me, and now, the law doesen't matter. So if this API can do it standalone it's perfect. The US or other countrys law matters are not a part of the question right now.

Answer (score 1):

Good news, everyone!

Starting with Java 6u181, 7u171 and 8u151 you will be able to programmatically change the policy with a call

```
 Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
```

If you have a security manager installed you will need to configure it to allow setting security property. More info in [JDK-8169716](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169716).

**Even better is that in Java 9, and also starting with future Java 6u181, 7u171, 8u162 releases the unlimited crypto will be enabled by default**! More info in [JDK-1870157](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170157)